# Python List initialization and modification producing 2 different results

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
n = 5
r = 6
C1 = [[0 for x in range(r+1)] for x in range(n+1)]
print(C1)
print()
C1[4][3] = 4
print(C1)

print()
print()

C2 = [[0] * (r+1)] * (n+1)
print(C2)
print()
C2[4][3] = 4
print(C2)
```

This is the output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

[[0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Why is it that when I use the 'for-range' way, I'm getting the right answer, but the []*n method is giving me the wrong answer? Both produce the same 2D array but when I try to modify it, I'm getting 2 different results!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that:

```
y2 = [foo() for _ in range(3)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
y2 = [foo(), foo(), foo()]
```

i.e. the expression is re-evaluated each time. Whereas:

```
y1 = [foo()] * 3
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = foo()
y1 = [x, x, x]
```

In your case, rather than `foo()` you're making a new list. So in the first case you get separate inner lists, whereas in the second case you get the *same* inner list referred to multiple times in the outer list.